# Decode Google Chrome cache file OSX

Tags: google-chrome, cache, browser-cache

How can I decode the Google Chrome cache files located in `/Users/[USER]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Profile [NUM]/Cache` named like `0a0b447d0216bd30_0` and looking like:

```
0\r�m����8��https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net/frontbucket/vendors~code-review-prefetch~create-workspace~dashboard-pull-requests-section~repository-routes~sear~6781f27c.d05f5b0cd5ba570bbf05.js�����s�:���+��]ξ�����ᜯWZ
Z�
t:o[IL�Xr���~����@����
S"����]�$�� ���^�IL����G������ܲ�T�ͳ���dur<t�i�ɀG&#�Hke��
�LO�K�"W�F�6znX$q���E(_<_0P@j�@ooz��
```

(Note: Only first couple of lines included here)

I found a bunch of year old solutions, including Windows exclusive apps and online services but none seem to work with this particular file.

Edit: Some progress: I copied my entire `/Users/[USER]/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome` from OSX to a Windows machine and then ran it inside NirSoft ChromeCacheView (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) which actually worked!

I got a list of all cached files and was able to save them to my desktop as their original filetype.

However, when opening the file (JSON in this case), it still looks like garbage :/

```
��闈*ޔ�ךѨ�JmJQ�y�����i�⠠��!v�$��V�v.�`Cd�|��
;U3�@���Nw���&����Fٗ���M���E���ɓ�&�f���
```

I believe they were packed with Brotli, is that why? If so, how can I decompress them to make them readable?

Edit2: More progress. Managed to run this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/brotli.1.html in a vagrant box and successfully decompressed the Brotli file! :)

Problem solved.